# Returning Promise in JavaScript es6

Tags: javascript, ajax, es6-promise

Let's say I have a file that is importing a function from the api and doing something with the result.

```
import api from './api'

const getData = () => {
  api.get(url)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I've seen two different styles for returning the response so the error bubbles up.

version 1:

```
get: (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios.get(url)
    .then(res => resolve(res))
    .catch(err => reject(err)) )
}
```

version 2:

```
get: (url) => {
  return axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.success == 200) {
        return Promise.resolve(res)
      }
      return Promise.reject(res)
    })
}
```

What are the differences between the two approaches? Is there a preferred/better method for error handling?

Comment: `then` also has an optional 2nd callback parameter that can be used instead of chaining `catch`.

Comment: Version 1 => You return a promise which pending to be resolved or rejected. Version 2 => You return a promise later which is resolved or rejected

Answer (score 2):

In general, two handy rules:

1. If your starting point is a promise (the return value of `axios.get`), then using `new Promise` is an anti-pattern. `then` and `catch` *already* create new promises.
2. Propagate errors, don't convert them to resolutions (until, of course, the point at which your handling those errors, usually near the beginning of the call chain).

Based on that, of those two options, you'd use Version 2, not Version 1.

Version 1 is a bit nonsensical: It eats the resolution value and converts errors to resolutions; it will always resolve to `undefined`. Remember that the result of the chain is the result of the last thing returned (or thrown) in a `then` or `catch` handler. Those two handlers don't return or throw anything, so the chain resolves (rather than rejecting) with `undefined`.

Version 2 does something: It modifies the promise result based on `res.success`. But it doesn't need `Promise.resolve`, it should just be:

```
get: (url) => axios.get(url).then(res => {
  if (res.success == 200) {
    return res;
  }
  return Promise.reject(res); // Or see note below
})
```

And there's a camp — which I agree with — which says you should always throw an `Error` object rather than returning `Promise.reject`, for stack trace info. So:

```
get: (url) => axios.get(url).then(res => {
  if (res.success == 200) {
    return res;
  }
  throw new Error(res/*...or something else useful here...*/);
})
```

Comment: *(If you see* "Version 1 is nonsense, it's exactly the same as..." *please hit refresh. I misread it.)*

Comment: Let's say api.get is being called in a React component, and I want the component to render the error message...would I go with version 2?

Comment: @crashspringfield: That's fine, if the code doing this is the ultimate consumer, you 1. Would use a `catch` handler (or the second argument to `then`), and 2. Wouldn't propagate the promise out of the method (not usually; on rare occasions, you want to both handle *and* propagate the error, in which case you `throw` in the `catch` handler after doing your handling). Which is indeed very like Version 1, just without returning the promise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference with the two versions, at the first one, you are creating a redundant `Promise`.

`axios.get`, is a function that returns a `Promise` there is no need to wrap it with another one.

You can warp with additional `Promise` if you wanna change the promise logic, meaning that if you wanna resolve no matter of what happened in axios promise.
Something like that:

```
get: (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => axios.get(url)
    .then(res => resolve(res))
    .catch(err => resolve(err)) )
}
```

but, usually it is not the practice.

Comment: *"There is no real difference with the two versions"* The fact the first one eats the resolution value and hides errors by converting them into resolutions is a fairly large difference. :-)

Comment: It is a possible usage, not recommending to do so, but sometime you need to wrap SDK or something similar. :]